# How to match a string enclosed in quotes

Tags: regex, powershell, powershell-2.0

I have a string, $line, where the contents are:

```
Filename="Longfilename"
```

I am trying to work out a regex to extract the string. I tried this:

```
$line -match "Filename=\"(?<TheFilename>[^\"]+)\"
```

where I am trying to capture Longfilename into $matches['TheFilename']

Unfortunately, this doesn't work.

How do I do this? Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that you did everying correctly, but add `Groups` property

```
$line = 'Filename="Longfilename"'
$matches = [regex]::Match($line, 'Filename=\"(?<TheFilename>[^\"]+)\"')
$matches.Groups['TheFilename']
```